# Unicode Three-D top-lighted rightwards equilateral arrowhead Symbol XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode

How would you typeset the ⮚ character in XeLaTeX (Unicode character 11162)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\font\myfont = "Wingdings"

\begin{document}%
\raggedright

\myfont\XeTeXglyph190

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{ifthen}`, `\raggedright`. For what?

Answer (score 4):

Just load a [font which has the symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b9a/fontsupport.htm).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\symbola{Symbola}
\begin{document}

{\symbola\symbol{"2B9A}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}

\ding{226}


\end{document}
```

for more symbols refer page {https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters}